# ASP.Net MVC Populate dropdown from a database with Distinct values

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am very new to this MVC framework and trying to figure out a very simple operation - Populate a Dropdown List from a Database. I managed to get a list of values from DB, but for some reason unable to get a distinct list. Here is my sample code

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private PlanContext _context = new PlanContext();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var query = _context.Categories.Select(m => new { m.ID }).Distinct();
        ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(query.AsEnumerable(), "ID", "ID");
        return View();
    }
}

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<p>
    Select a Category:<%= Html.DropDownList("ID", (SelectList) ViewBag.CategoryID, "---Select One---") %>
</p>
</asp:Content>

public class PlanContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

[Table("vCategory")]
public class Category : IEquatable<Category>
{
    [Column("CategoryID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Category other)
    {
        //Check whether the compared object is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;

        //Check whether the compared object references the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

        return ID == other.ID;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

My Dropdown always has multiple items with same ID value. The table does have duplicate values but I am trying to just populate the DDL with Distinct ones.

Thanks for your help.

Javid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you are showing Entity Framework assumes by naming conventions that `ID` is the (primary) key property of the `Category` class. Because a key must be unique EF doesn't translate a `Distinct()` in LINQ into a `SELECT DISTINCT` in SQL because all key values in the table must be necessarily different. Applying `SELECT DISTINCT` would be redundant.

However, if your `ID` column is in fact not unique, it can't be the primary key and the mapping between your model and the database is incorrect. You should overhaul the mapping.

If the table has another column which is the primary key you should introduce a corresponding property in the model and make this property the key property (using data annotations or Fluent API).

If you are mapping to a "legacy" database and the table for some reason has no primary key at all, you can't create a mapping between table and a model class at all with EF, I believe, because every mapped class requires a key property which corresponds to a primary key in the database table. Your best workaround would probably be to load the distinct category IDs by using direct SQL (`SELECT DISTINCT`) to query this (not mapped) table.

Comment: thanks. In my case, the table I am trying to query has two columns category and product. I need to get a list of distinct categories. In this case, how do I define an entity that maps to a table with multiple columns but my entity just have one column as proprty?

Comment: @user320587: It's not possible. What is the primary key in the database table? `ProductId` or `CategoryId`+`ProductId` (composite key)? You need to map this database key to a key in your model class.

Comment: Thanks. The View in DB does not have any PK, since most of my work is readonly. In my EF, I marked two columns as Key to create a composite and it seems to be working fine. Thanks so much for your help.